# A noun that describes the possession of esoteric knowledge

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'm trying to come up with a noun that is more descriptive (or at least carries more tone) than "knowledge" and more succinct than "esoteric knowledge and trivia". Rather than saying "this person possesses a great deal of esoteric knowledge and trivia" I'd like to be able to say

> This person possesses a great deal of _______.

For more clarification: I'm hoping to describe a character very similar to Sherlock; someone who collects an overabundance of seemingly useless knowledge on the off chance that it becomes relevant.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Esoterica**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/esoterica)

> *plural noun*
>
> things understood by or meant for a select few; recondite matters or items.

[Dictionary.com]

Answer (score 5):

I would say “[arcanum](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/arcana)” (pluralized as “arcana”) most closely fits the definition you want. This is M-W’s first definition of it:

> *noun*
>
> : mysterious or specialized knowledge, language, or information accessible or possessed only by the initiate—usually used in plural

Answer (score 2):

"Trivia" sounds like exactly the word you're looking for here.

From [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/trivia):

> Details, considerations, or pieces of information of little importance or value.

Comment: By their very nature, though, trivia are not esoteric: they’re trivial.

Comment: Yes, I concur with Janus Bahs Jacquet. [*Trivia*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trivia) simply means “unimportant matters.” It doesn’t denote esoteric knowledge in any sense.

Comment: The asker of the question asked specifically for useless information. Per the asker's comment on the original question, "For more clarification: I'm hoping to describe a character very similar to Sherlock; someone who collects an overabundance of seemingly useless knowledge on the off chance that it becomes relevant." This elaboration indicates that the original word choice "esoteric" was not ideal.

Comment: @R Mac I'll not assume that the word "esoteric" is less than ideal if the OP did not explicitly say so. The OP said as follows: "*Rather than saying 'this person possesses a great deal of **esoteric knowlege and trivia**' I'd like to be able to say,*

*This person possesses a great deal of _______.*

Comment: The OP did say so in a comment. I quoted the comment...

Comment: @RMac No, the OP did not say that “the original word choice ‘esoteric’ was not ideal,” as you said [here.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/466876/a-noun-that-describes-the-possession-of-esoteric-knowledge/466878#comment1126982_466878) The OP was simply providing clarification and context in that comment.